# Importing Correlation Matrix

Tags: r, r-corrplot

I have a ready-made correlation matrix to visualize in `R` with `corrplot` (or other relevant) package. I do not have raw data to produce correlations with `cor()` function.

The problem is just to import the matrix from a .csv file and to perform some actions (visualisation, dendritic graph and so on) with it. However, `R` does not recognize the matrix as such where `corrplot` can be applied. I used

```
M<-read.csv("myfile.csv")
```

then

```
Mcor <- as.matrix(M)
```

Next, I added identical names of rows and columns:

```
rownames(Mcor)<-my_cols_names
colnames(Mcor)<-my_cols_names
```

It shows the structure, identical to the "true" correlation matrix, produced from raw data with `cor()`:

```
> str(Mcor)
 num [1:25, 1:25] 1 0.58 -0.43 -0.39 0.06 0.1 -0.3 -0.2 -0.06 -0.3 ...
 - attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
 ..$ : chr [1:25] "V1" "V2" "V3" "V4" ...
 ..$ : chr [1:25] "V1" "V2" "V3" "V4" ...
```

However, `corrplot(Mcor)` gives

> Error in corrplot(Mcor) : The matrix is not in [-1, 1]!

The problem appeared trivial and caused by a typo mistake in entering data: one number appeared to be >1.

The way to check this, as suggested in comments: 
1)run the command

any(abs(Mcor)>1)

it gives TRUE, if there are wrong numbers in data (absolute values >1)

2) subsequently try to draw correlation plots for smaller sets:

corrplot(Mcor[1:5,1:5])

then

corrplot(Mcor[1:10,1:10])

until the error (wrong column) is localized (failure to build a plot with (n+1)x(n+1) matrix, if nxn is OK). Or directly reveal the wrong number(s), for example, with *which* command

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Easily input a correlation matrix in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9307420/easily-input-a-correlation-matrix-in-r)

Comment: what does `any(abs(Mcor)>1)` return (the error message suggests it could be true) . If so, and you are sure its a correlation matrix that you have imported , then it could be a rounding issue. You could try `corrplot(round(Mcor, 4))`

Comment: It yields FALSE, the data as such seems to be OK. Something wrong with types/cohercion (?)

Comment: types look okay from str. Please try `corrplot(Mcor[1:5, 1:5])` to see if it works for a small numer of values.

Comment: It yields FALSE, the data as such seems to be OK. Rounding does not work either. So, the issue is likely from faulty cohercion when importing csv data (issues with double precision?) Or, for example matrix is not symmetric (it should be, but who knows, maybe some typo)

Comment: So can you plot with the subset of data from comment above? if not can you share the results of `dput(Mcor[1:5, 1:5])` please. ps. corrplot wouldnt throw an error if it is no symmetric (`corrplot::corrplot(matrix(runif(4), 2))`)

Comment: It worked! Up to corrplot(Mcor[1:18, 1:18]) inclusively. And inspecting data revealed a typo in the 19-th column with a number >1.
 any(abs(Mcor)>1) returned FALSE because of another typo mistake in that command (misplaced operator >1 and one bracket). So the problem is trivial.

Comment: okay, good stuff